# kubernetes: kubectl only streams a certain amount of logs

Tags: logging, kubernetes, kubectl

I have created a pod that produces several millions of log lines.

However `kubectl logs -f <pod_name>` at some point stops and the output freezes.

Here is my experiment:

```
kubectl logs --follow=true test-logs-job-13263-t5dbx | tee file1
kubectl logs --follow=true test-logs-job-13263-t5dbx | tee file2
kubectl logs --follow=true test-logs-job-13263-t5dbx | tee file3
```

Each of the above processes was interrupted (`Ctrl+C`) as soon as I stopped receiving any input on my screen.

So:

```
$ wc -l file*
  106701 file1
  106698 file2
  106698 file3
  320097 total
```

It is worth mentioning also that each of these files contains different logs, i.e. the actual logs that were streamed at the time the `kubectl logs -f` command was actually executed.

Is there a setting that limits the max  amount of logs to be streamed to the above number? (~10700)

My cluster is on GKE for what that matters.

**edit**: For some reason this seem to happen **only** on GKE; when I run the same experiment on another k8s cluster ([`katakoda`](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes/playground)) the logs were streamed without any issue whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes does not provide logging itself but uses what the container engine provides. If you were running without kubernetes on a plain docker installation the default configuration of docker is to use the json-file driver and keep 10 mb of logs per container.
See https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/
If you need a huge amount of logs consider using central logging infrastructure and configure log forwarding. (This is supported by docker as well for several logging backends, see https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#supported-logging-drivers )

There is a bug reported that log rotation can interrupt the streaming of kubectl logs --follow: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/28369

Comment: I accepted your answer although this was actually restricted in `systemd` docker service file, i.e. in `/etc/docker/default`: `$ cat /etc/default/docker
DOCKER_OPTS="-p /var/run/docker.pid --iptables=false --ip-masq=false --log-level=warn --bip=169.254.123.1/24 --registry-mirror=https://mirror.gcr.io --log-driver=json-file --log-opt=max-size=10m --log-opt=max-file=5 --insecure-registry 10.0.0.0/8"`. Changing the value of `10m` and restarting the service on all nodes solved the problem.

Comment: For GKE you might consider to use stackdriver/logging which uses [fluentd](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/customizing-stackdriver-logs-fluentd) as a logging agent.  Logs are stored for up to 30 days with all benefits like:
- Structured logging,
- Exporting to BigQuery,
- Alerting, 
- Error reporting